# Link to a div and trigger a jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, product

I have a product page for a client, which they add products to dynamically via a SilverStripe CMS. You can see the preview of that here http://codepen.io/lucymacgregor/pen/EgBRmG

My issue is that I have to link from the home page to one of the activated product previews. The previews don't have their own page, they are just a show and hide div via some jQuery script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".show").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('.product-wrap').find('.product-box').fadeIn('slow');
    return false;
  });

  $(".hide").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('.product-wrap').find('.product-box').fadeOut('slow');
    return false;
  });
});
```

So I can link to that product page, but how do I link to the div (they don't have custom names because of the dynamic need) whilst simultaneously having the show function activated to the div so that it opens in the preview mode for that product?

I was thinking it could somehow search for a title and open the div based off that, but I have no idea how to execute that.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign the div an id, you can link to the url and append the id to the end (e.g. http://website.com/products#laptop )

And once the document is ready, parse the urls for hashes (`window.location.hash`) and use that information to display the div with the matching ID attribute.

---

By the way, if I were do do something like this, I'd also likely change the click handlers to simply update the hash, and listen for hash changes to toggle the div (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange), so that the logic always follows the same flow of control.

---

OH! I also forgot to mention - CSS has some support of hash `:target` logic as well which is cool. You can read about it here - https://css-tricks.com/on-target/  So you could potentially skip the javascript and use CSS for this only, depending on how complex you need the reaction to the hash change to be.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example to set and get `location.hash` like this.

> http://yours/page/#product-box_page_id_1
>
> http://yours/page/#product-box_page_id_2

**UPDATE**: it's recommended to set each div with unique id and avoid any issues if your div's generated dynamically e.g. Ajax. but you can avoid this by check url hash after all div's loaded successfully.

Below code will parse URL hash to find `2nd` div has class `.product-box` and `fadeIn()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".show").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var div = $(this).parents('.product-wrap').find('.product-box');

    //set location hash to be #product-box_page_id_1
    location.hash = div.attr("class") + "_page_id_" + div.index("body");

    div.fadeIn('slow');
    return false;
  });

  $(".hide").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('.product-wrap').find('.product-box').fadeOut('slow');

    //remove url hash
    location.hash = "";

    return false;
  });

   //below code should be called after all div's loaded.
   //get hash, parse and find targeted div and fadeIn();
  if (location.hash.replace("#","").length>0) {
    var divT = location.hash.replace("#", "").split("_page_id_");
    if ($("." + divT[0]).length) $("body ." + divT).eq(+divT[1]).fadeIn('slow');
  }

});
```